# enterprise compiler issue

Tags: enterprise, aix

I was trying to compile something on my pc with IBM XL C/C++ Enterprise Edition V8.0 for AIX
I got a error like:

"aaalib.c", line #... something else: It refered to a variable that isn't initialized here.

It works fine when compiled with gcc in linux.  But I still would like to know why or if anyone has experienced something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a valid warning that you are using an uninitialised variable. You should investigate and fix the bug. Just because the code *appears* to work doesn't mean that you don't have latent bug(s). Post the code for the function where the error occurs if you need help identifying the problem.